# failed to read XRef stream pdfworker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation

I am new to java script.I am getting an error in console Invalid Xref Stream. Its coming from pdf.worker.js.. Any clue why we get this error?

```
$scope.loadPDF = function(path) {
            // /!\ Function modified from library in order to mamage error view on pdf display /!\
            console.log('loadPDF ', path);
            $scope.$parent.$parent.isPdfError = false;
            PDFJS.getDocument(path, null, null, $scope.documentProgress).then(function(_pdfDoc) {
                $scope.pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
                $scope.renderPage($scope.pageNum, function(success) {
                    if ($scope.loadProgress) {
                        $scope.loadProgress({state: "finished", loaded: 0, total: 0});
                    }
                });
            }, function(message, exception) {
                console.log("PDF load error: " + message);
                $scope.$parent.$parent.isPdfError = true;
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$digest();
                if ($scope.loadProgress) {
                     $rootScope.completeProgress();
                    $scope.loadProgress({state: "error", loaded: 0, total: 0});
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: the PDF document is corrupt

Comment: I've read that if a server uses chunked encoding you can also get this error - does it happen with all pdf's or just a particular pdf

Comment: It happens the first time.. i open a pdf.. and then if i exit the page and come back it gets resolved

Comment: are you opening a pdf directly in the browser? i.e. going to a page like `http://somedoman.com/somefile.pdf`

Comment: not..we open the pdf form in a box on the page itself

Comment: how is this being done - by code? show the code

Comment: I have added the code above.. We have used pdf.worker.js javascript library.